# Content-type: text/csv output html into the csv file

Tags: php, html, csv, fputcsv

I can't seem to output only specific information, into a csv or any file.  The following, e.g., output the html from the page, rather than the data that I'm trying to send to the Applicants.csv:

(the $a_Lines array has already been populated):

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Applicants.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ( $a_Lines as $row ) {
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in expression

```
fputcsv($file, $row);
```

$row is always array. If you want to create from $a_Lines csv file, then you don't need foreach loop (of course, I presume that $a_Lines is array). In case that you want selected data from $a_Lines array, then run through $a_Lines, create new array or transform existing one and after the loop add prepared array into fputcsv function.

Comment: Thanks, Dean.  Yes, I confirmed with a var_dump() that $row is an array.  Earlier in the day, it was a string, which generated an error relevant to your comments.  But $row is an array now, for each iteration.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the problem is, that this needs to be a separate html page.  Currently, it's part of a condition, of a larger page.  But maybe I need to assign the CSV button (in the main page) to a url of another page.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: You can have only one output on page. So if you have something before as output, then you have to change that. Otherwise, it is not the problem. You can do one more thing - try to remove double quotes around filename.

Comment: Ok, I'll separate this on a separate page. And take out the double quotes. – Thanks.